# Am I done with this Linked List code?

Tags: c#, linked-list

Hi I'm trying to get some practice with Linked Lists.

I Defined an Object class called `Student`:

```
public class Student
{
      protected string  Student_Name;
      protected int Student_ID;
      protected int Student_Mark;
      protected char    Student_Grade;

      public Student()  // default Constructor
      {
         Student_Name = "           ";
         Student_ID = 0;
         Student_Mark = 0;
         Student_Grade = ' ';
        }

      public Student(string Sname, int Sid, int Smark, char Sgrade) // Constructor
      {
         int len = sname.Length;
         Student_Name = sname.Substring(0, len);
         //Student_Name = sname.Substring(0, sname.Length);
         Student_ID = Sid;
         Student_Mark = Smark;
         Student_Grade = Sgrade;
      }
}
```

and then a `Node` class:

```
public class S_Node
{
      public Student    Element;
      public S_Node Link;

      public S_Node()
      {
         Element = new Student();
         Link = null;
      }

      public Node(Student theElement)
      {
         Element = theElement;
         Link = null;
      }
}
```

and the `LinkedList`:

```
public class S_LinkedList
{
    protected S_Node header;
    protected S_Node tail;

    public S_LinkedList()
    {
       header = new S_Node();
       Tail = new S_Node();
       header.Link = Tail;
    }

    // METHODS which i don't know how to do it (never use linkedlist before)
}
```

I need to organize this data using a “linkedlist data structure type”.

Contain all methods of linkedlist as Adding nodes to the list as I've learned -->(Insert),Deleting nodes from the list,as I've learned -->((Remove),Traversing the lists I've learned -->((PrintList),Finding a node in the list as I've learned -->((Find , FindPrevious) the problem I'm selflearning and I've tried to search the net and read more from the stupid C# that was a disaster.
I've done too much that I'm so sad that i don't know how to complete it .

I'm trying hard to Use this classes to write an executable program and to Test it .

If you don't want to help in completing this program (hope not) at least show me some real examples or ideas , after all I'm a selflearner geek :-)

Comment: "linked list array" doesn't make sense to me.  It's either a linked list, or it's an array (what you describe is a linked list).  I don't know of anything that's both.

Comment: I tried editing the question to make a little more sense, but the paragraph towards the bottom (starting with "Contain all") is just too confusing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 the head of the list.
 ( item1
   Element: student1
   Next ------------> ( item2
  )                     Element: student2
                        Next ------------> ( item3
                      )                      Element: student3
                                             Next: null
                                           )
                                           the tail of the list.
```

First of all, for you to be able to write the StudentList class, you need to write the client code first. Client code is the code that uses your student list. Also, don't just write one thing at a time and throw it away. Instead write a whole bunch of [test] cases that exercise the different ways you *need* to interact with the StudentList. Write exceptional cases too. But don't be tempted to write a swiss-army knife of a class that does everything just because it can. Write the minimal amount of code that gets the job done.

How you need to use the class will heavily dictate how the class is constructed. This is the essence of TDD or Test Driven Design.

Your biggest problem that I can see is you have no idea how you want to use the class. So lets do that first.

```
// create a list of students and print them back out.
StudentList list = new StudentList();
list.Add( new Student("Bob", 1234, 2, 'A') );
list.Add( new Student("Mary", 2345, 4, 'C') );

foreach( Student student in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
}
```

I add the students to the list, and then I print them out.

I have no need for my client code to see inside the StudentList. Therefore StudentList hides how it implements the linked list. Let's write the basics of the StudentList.

```
public class StudentList 
{
    private ListNode _firstElement; // always need to keep track of the head.

    private class ListNode
    {
        public Student Element { get; set; }
        public ListNode Next { get; set; }
    }

    public void Add(Student student) { /* TODO */ }

}
```

StudentList is pretty basic. Internally it keeps track of the first or head nodes. Keeping track of the first node is obviously always required.

You also might wonder why ListNode is declared inside of StudentList. What happens is the ListNode class is only accessible to the StudentList class. This is done because StudentList doesn't want to give out the details to it's internal implementation because it is controlling all access to the list. StudentList  never reveals how the list is implemented. Implementation hiding is an important OO concept.

If we did allow client code to directly manipulate the list, there'd be no point having StudentList is the first place.

Let's go ahead and implement the Add() operation.

```
public void Add(Student student)
{
    if (student == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("student");

    // create the new element
    ListNode insert = new ListNode() { Element = student };

    if( _firstElement == null )
    {
        _firstElement = insert;
        return;
    }

    ListNode current = _firstElement;
    while (current.Next != null)
    {
        current = current.Next;
    }

    current.Next = insert;
}
```

The Add operation has to find the last item in the list and then puts the new ListNode at the end. Not terribly efficient though. It's currently O(N) and Adding will get slower as the list gets longer.

Lets optimize this a little for inserts and rewrite the Add method. To make Add faster all we need to do is have StudentList keep track of the last element in the list.

```
private ListNode _lastElement;  // keep track of the last element: Adding is O(1) instead of O(n)

public void Add(Student student)
{
    if( student == null )
        throw new ArgumentNullException("student");

    // create the new element
    ListNode insert = new ListNode() { Element = student };

    if (_firstElement == null)
    {
        _firstElement = insert;
        _lastElement = insert;
        return;
    }

    // fix up Next reference
    ListNode last = _lastElement;
    last.Next = insert;
    _lastElement = insert;
}
```

Now, when we add, we don't iterate. We just need to keep track of the head and tail references.

Next up: the foreach loop. StudentList is a collection, and being a collection we want to enumerate over it and use C#'s `foreach`. The C# compiler can't iterate magically. In order to use the foreach loop We need to provide the compiler with an enumerator to use even if the code we write doesn't explicitly appear to use the enumerator.

First though, lets re-visit how we iterate over a linked list.

```
// don't add this to StudentList
void IterateOverList( ListNode current )
{
    while (current != null)
    {
        current = current.Next;
    }
}
```

Okay. so let's hook into C#'s foreach loop and return an enumerator. To do that we alter StudentList to implement IEnumerable. This is getting a little bit advanced, but you should be able to figure out what's going on.

```
// StudentList now implements IEnumerable<Student>
public class StudentList : IEnumerable<Student>
{
    // previous code omitted

    #region IEnumerable<Student> Members
    public IEnumerator<Student> GetEnumerator()
    {
        ListNode current = _firstElement;

        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Element;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You should be able to spot the linked list iteration in there. Don't get thrown by the `yield` keyword. All yield is doing is returning the current student back to the foreach loop. The enumarator stops returning students when it gets to the end of the linked list.

And that's it! The code works the way we want it to.

---

* This is by no means the only way to implement the list. I've opted to put the list logic in the StudentList and keep ListNode very basic. But the code does only what my very first unit test needs and nothing more. There are more optimizations you could make, and there are other ways of constructing the list.

Going forward: What you need to do is first create [unit] tests for what your code needs to do, then add the implementation you require.

---

* fyi I also rewrote the Student class. Bad naming and strange casing from a C# persepctive, not to mention the code you provided doesn't compile. I prefer the `_` as a leader to private member variables. Some people don't like that, however you're new to this so I'll leave them in because they're easy to spot.

```
public class Student
{
    private string _name;
    private int _id;
    private int _mark;
    private char _letterGrade;

    private Student()  // hide default Constructor
    { }

    public Student(string name, int id, int mark, char letterGrade) // Constructor
    {
        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) )
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        if( id <= 0 )
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("id");

        _name = name;
        _id = id;
        _mark = mark;
        _letterGrade = letterGrade;
    }
    // read-only properties - compressed to 1 line for SO answer.
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public int Id { get { return _id; } }
    public int Mark { get { return _mark; } }
    public char LetterGrade { get { return _letterGrade; } }
}
```

- check parameters
- pay attention to the different casing of properties, classes, and variables.
- hide the default constructor. Why do I want to create students without real data?
- provide some read-only properties.

  - This class is immutable as written (i.e. once you create a student, you can't change it).

Answer (score 2):

I'll do one for you! You need to draw diagrams with each node as a box, and work out what code you need to use to change the list for each operation. See this for some inspiration:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

The diagrams there don't show the main list class as a box, which you should have, with two arrows coming out of it for the header and tail.

Draw yourself some diagrams for the two cases in the Insert method to work out what's going on. One diagram for when there's nothing in the list and header is null, and another diagram for when there's something already in the list. Then from there work out the other operations.

```
public class S_LinkedList {

    protected S_Node header = null;

    protected S_Node tail = null;

    public S_LinkedList()
    {
    }

    // METHODS which i don't know how to do it (never use linkedlist before)
    void Insert(Student s)
    {
        if( header == null )
        {
            header = new S_Node(s);
            tail = header;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.Link = new S_Node(s);
            tail = tail.Link;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried somethin similer to this scott but It wont work

why ?!

public void Insert(Object newItem, Object after)

{

 Node current = new Node();


 Node newNode = new Node(newItem);

 current = Find(after);

 newNode.Link = current.Link;

 current.Link = newNode;

}

Comment: Not sure. That code kind of looks right. Remember if the insert is at the end of the list, then tail will need updating to refer to the new node. You need to say what it is you see that makes you think it doesn't work. Does it compile? Does it run without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 2):

The operations you are missing are:

**Add:**

set the link of the tail node to be the added node and set the tail to be the new node.

**Remove/Delete:**

is a bit tricky if you don't have a doubly linked list but with a singly linked list go throught he list from the head till you find the node you require keeping the previous node in a separate variable. When you find the node you are removing set the Link of the previous node to that nodes link. An optimization might be to check that it's not the link you are looking for.
Alternatively make it a doubly linked list and you don't need to keep track of the previous node.

**Find:**

Traverse the list from node to node till you find the one you are looking for.

read this [wikipedia article for more info.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this...](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives3/archive478.html)

Although if you really want to learn how to do this you should write it in c or c++ at least then you'd be doing something useful...

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't see a reason to write your own linked list in C# (other then learning how it works) since the .NET already contains LinkedList generic class.

Comment: you are right but I want to try it , I'm even now trying to create my own math class instead of the bulit in math class that includ GCD and LCM I really like to do it ( I will call it MyMath :-) ) . So can you please help

Answer (score 1):

The concept of linked lists is not very difficult to understand. Implementation on the other hand ... can get a bit tricky.

I can also understand your frustration of trying to find information on the web about it. I have been in your boat before and everything varies from site to site. You really might want to invest in a data structures book as you I think the information you find will be much more clear and helpful than most information you find in the wild.

Implementing a linked list in Java/C# will be much easier if you have never used ll's before. However, once you get a better feel for it you will get a much better understanding for the ll's by creating them in C/C++.

From your code above, you will be better off thinking of each S_Node as just regular node that contains a Student object instead of thinking of it as a Student node (hope that makes sense). Same rules apply for your S_LinkedList class. A linked list is a list mode up of nodes. These nodes contain Student objects.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this as your Student class.**

```
public class Student
{
    protected string Name;
    protected int ID;
    protected int Mark;
    protected char Grade;

    public Student()  // default Constructor
    {
        Name = "";
        ID = 0;
        Mark = 0;
        Grade = '';
    }

    public Student(string Name, int ID, int Mark, char Grade) // Constructor
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Mark = Mark;
        this.Grade = Grade;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still can't get an executable program

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as I read it, is too vague.  I would start by googling 'linked lists' or picking up a book on 'data structures'.  When you run into a specific problem, ask it on here, and I'm sure someone will help you.

Comment: well I'm in a problem and I've done a big part and I'm really sick of using google i found thousand of articls and each one is  diffrent from the another if you know an example somewhere that is similer to this please post.